# Git repository not found can't pull

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push in new repository but i'm getting error.
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'repository link'
Don't know what to do i googled it but didn't find any useful answer...

Comment: Have you created the repository on github? If so it will tell you the url to use for origin. Then it is a question of whether you set it up correctly. I would suggest using ssh approach. If you are using http, then you need to use a token rather than your actual password, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the repository was not found. The repository either does not exist or some entries are missing from the config of your .ssh folder. If you want to create a repository, then you will need to create it somewhere, it seems you use GitHub, so that's a possibility. One your repository exists, look at its URL, make sure that you have an ssh key and that your ssh key has access to the repo. Also, double-check the path.